# An error occurs when using some () in *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

There are two lists as follows.

```
article = [
  {
  "id": 600,
  "components": [
    {
      "kind": "text",
      "text": "texttext",
    },
    {
      "kind": "title",
      "text": "titletile",
    },
  ]
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 26,
      "name": "restaurant",
    },
    {
      "id": 51,
      "name": "special",
    }
  ],
  }
];

categoryLists = [
 "children" : [
  {
    "id": 19,
    "name": "extreme"
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "name": "series"
  },
  {
    "id": 51,
    "name": "special"
  },
 ]
];
```

I want to display `category.name` when ngFor handles `article.categories` and `category.id` exists in `categoryLists.children` with ngIf.
I implemented it in the template as follows.

```
<div *ngFor="let category of article.categories">
  <p *ngIf="categoryLists.children.some(e => e.id === category.id)">{{ category.name }}</p>
</div>
```

However, the following error occurred.

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments
```

Why is this?
Is there a problem with some ()?

The following processing is done without problems, so there should be no problem with the array.

```
<div *ngFor="let child in categoryLists.children">
  <p>{{ child.name }}</p>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let category in article.categories">
  <p>{{ category.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you cannot use a js function inside of a  ngIf case

Comment: @RahulSingh is right, you can wrap your statement in ts file:
function foo(categoryId: number): boolean {
    return categoryLists.children.some(e => e.id === categoryId)
}
and then call it in html template:
<p *ngIf="foo(category.id)">{{ category.name }}</p>

Comment: if you want filter based on the value in the list try and use angular pipes that will filter the value based on your lists, its better to use angular pipes for your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RahulSingh is right, you can wrap your statement in ts file:

```
function foo(categoryId: number): boolean {
    return categoryLists.children.some(e => e.id === categoryId)
}
```

and then call it in html template:

```
<p *ngIf="foo(category.id)">{{ category.name }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the arrow function has to return the computed value of `e.id === category.id` keep it in the braces as in the following code. Else, it first checks for `e => e.id` which is not required behaviour.

```
<div *ngFor="let category of article.categories">
  <p *ngIf="categoryLists.children.some(e => (e.id === category.id))">{{ category.name }}</p>
</div>
```

All the best.